# Amd drivers don't load on boot and I have to sudo modprobe it, possibly related to r8168-dkms failing to build

Tags: drivers, kernel, realtek, amdgpu

After starting my system up, I get stuck on 1024x768, then I have to log in, open a terminal and type in`sudo modprobe amdgpu`.

After that, the screen flashes a few times, becomes black with a flashing cursor and I have to Ctrl+Alt+2 to tty2, then Ctrl+Alt+1 back to tty1 and log in again.

After that I can tether my phone for a network connection.
My current setup. I tried to update to the pro drivers, because I get framedrops in multiple games.

```
7:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev e1)
Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Nitro+ Radeon RX 570/580/590
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

It happened on 20.04, now I updated to 20.10 and it still the same and I have tried all solutions I could find, but none helped. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share with us the result of `cat /etc/default/grub` please? There may be a way to get the amdgpu module to run at boot time.

Comment: I ended up making a backup and reinstalling 20.04, because the system was unstable when using both OpenGL and Vulkan API. I can tell you that I did try [this](https://randomblog.hu/fix-amdgpu-driver-problems-for-your-amd-video-card-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-upgrading-to-a-new-kernel/), but it didn't help.

The most interesting thing I don't understand is why did switching between tty1 and 2 fix the blinking cursor issue.

Comment: There is no information about hardware. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.